# Should I write clickListeners inside onCreate() method or should I create a separate method with onClick attribute in XML file in android studio?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio

I am currently taking Android dev classes and working on a small app. I have written my code with separate methods for the clickListeners outside my `onCreate` method like below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void numberActivity(View view) {
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numbers);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Numbers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), NumbersActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

However, I saw in the sample code from the lessons that the code was written inside `onCreate()` method like below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);

    numbers.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            
            Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class);

            startActivity(numbersIntent);
        }
    });
```

So, my question is which way is more correct? In either cases the app is launching and the listeners are working. I would like to know which way is better for the performance and speed of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should add all your onClickListeners in your java code and not in xml.
However I think it is completely irrelevant for performance if you add them in onCreate or a method you call in onCreate. This is only a question of what is more convenient for you and/or better to read and understand.

Comment: Great to know that. Appreciate for your advice and help. I think I found the answer already for the difference.